# When trying to append a FormFile to a FormFile[] (array) the FormFile is null

Tags: c#, arrays, append, iformfile

I have a FormFile[] that when I try adding a non-null FormFile object to it the array does not show any values.

```
     FormFile[] fileArray = new FormFile[10];
     FormFile myFile = new FormFile( /*Excel File*/ );
     fileArray.Append(myFile);
```

myFile[0] = null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `System.Linq.Append` this will return an new array with the value added at the end.
If you do the following:

```
 FormFile[] fileArray = new FormFile[10];
 FormFile myFile = new FormFile( /*Excel File*/ );
 var newFileArray = fileArray.Append(myFile);
```

`newFileArray[11]` will contain `myFile`